# How not to update linked through @ManyToOne entity in JPA if it causes too much updates in audit tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, audit

We have 2 `@Entity`s having fields like that:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "audit", value = "tariff_option")
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
@Table(name = "tariff_option")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {}, callSuper = true)
@ToString()
public class TariffOption extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6398231779406280786L;

    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dict_tariff_id", updatable = false)
    private DictTariff tariff;
}
```

and

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(schema = "audit", value = "dict_tariff")
@AuditOverride(forClass = BaseEntity.class, isAudited = true)
@Table(name = "dict_tariff")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {}, callSuper = true)
@ToString(exclude = {"contractorTypes", "service", "tariffOptions", "dictTariffOptions"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"contractorTypes", "service", "tariffOptions", "dictTariffOptions"})
public class DictTariff extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3881580795280130829L;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tariff", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TariffOption> tariffOptions;
}
```

and then when we save the `dictTariffOption` variable of `TariffOption` class, the associated `dictTariff` of `DictTariff` class is saved because of `@ManyToOne` annotation and ownership of the tie by the `dictTariffOption`:

```
repository.save(dictTariffOption)
```

This causes problem that on any change of `dictTariffOption` the `dictTariff` is saved again with the same values. That causes the new entry in audit scheme what we want to avoid.

I tried `EntityManager.detach(dictTariff)` right before saving the `dictTariffOption`, but it doesn't help. So what is the approach to ignore the update of the linked entity? I also tried to re-retireve it right before the save to make it not to be JPA-dirty, but it doesn't help and it got updated.

```
jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: rf.dom.billing.model.common.postgres.CustomPostgreSqlDialect
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            default_schema: audit
```

Comment: you didn't show the dictTariffOption mapping in your entity definitions, so there is nothing to go on explaining why you might see or have problems with dictTariffOption and tariffOptions. If you have two references (Lists?) to the same object type and the same data, make sure object instance identity is maintained in them. JSON deserialization is known to have issues as it doesn't abide by JPA specified object identity if building a DictTarriff - you'll have to give it information to know that the same TariffOption instance is used multiple times within an object graph.

Comment: @Chris dictTarifOption variable is actually TariffOption Entity, that was my typo

Comment: @Chris so the question is how not to update `dictTariff` entityvariable of `DictTariff` entity explicitly after I have updated and saved the `dictTariffOption` varible of `TariffOption` entity.

Comment: I still do not follow - please update/edit your question. What exactly is 'saved' in the situation you are describing? JPA deals with persist and merge calls, and since you have not specified the cascade merge option on the relationship, changes within the TariffOption.tariff instance itself should not get pick up. At least, not through that reference. Are you maybe read in in the TariffOption and DictTariff instances in the same transaction and making changes? Anything read in is managed, so you don't even need to call save for changes to be synchronized to the database when commit occurs

Comment: Also what is 'audit' here? Are you using envers or some other tool hooked into hibernate that maybe is picking up lifecycle events that are picking up changes when there are none, or are there actual update statements occurring to the DictTariff somehow.

Comment: @Chris `dictTariff` instance is retrieved from the DB in order just to get some values from it and no setter is called for it. But JPA marks it as 'dirty' and when the `tariffOption` is updated JPA tries to save the dictTariff again with no clear reason. I see the update calls for the `dictTariff` there. Once the update call is done, the new line is added to the audit schema table, bearing exactly the same values in all columns that were before. So the question is how to avoid JPA consider `dictTariff` needed to be updated on `.save(tariffOption)`

Comment: "JPA marks it as 'dirty'" - what are you using to figure that out? How is JPA (Hibernate, not JPA) trying to 'save the dictTariff again' exactly - is the update call you refer to something to do with your auditing, an auditing tool, or an actual update statement to update columns with 'new' values. To be clear, you have the audited annotation, but not mentioned hibernate envers (Not JPA at all) as the tool used for auditing, and your question seemed aimed at an extra entity insert, not an auditing table issue. Add more detail and specifics- does it always occur, or just on some changes?

Comment: I can't actually figure that out, but since dictTariff isn't updated in any place of the code but then I see the update sql query for it, it's probably done by Hibernate. And yes, there is a hibernate enver for audit, I have updated the question. And the audit insert (on dictTariff update) occurs on every tariffOption creation

Comment: When you create a new TariffOption, you are modifying the DictTariff.tariffOptions list. You've changed it, so it triggers an audit. I can't find where this is described, but the reason is pretty obvious from the example on https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/ - it allows you to audit the number of values in the DictTariff.tariffOptions collection. If you don't want it, exclude it from being audited, or don't map it from the DictTariff side.

Comment: @Chris thanks, I can't exclude it as I need it to be mapped, but I I don't wan't them to be audited, how I can exclude the audit for the particular collection field?

Comment: Not sure - envers docs will have to guide you as I've never used it, but by exclude, I was referring to their annotations, excluding it from auditing. https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa shows a @NotAudited annotation

Comment: @Chris if I just remove mapping on DictTariff side, but still will keep it on the TariffOption side, will that work as expected (i.e adding dictTariff link to TariffOption still will be updated to the db, while nothing will affect the dictTariff entity and the entityManager won't try to save that as like it was updated)?

Comment: This isn't JPA or an entityManager problem, it is Envers. You should tag it as hibernate-envers since that is what you are using. I don't know  it, but I would guess it is fine since there is nothing mapped to track on the DictTariff side of things for it to audit.

Comment: @Chris could you please put your comment about the `@NotAudited` as the official answer, it was that what helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Chris,

```
public class DictTariff extends BaseEntity {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tariff", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotAudited
private List<TariffOption> tariffOptions;
```

helped and no longer update the audit changes on `DictTariff` when whe `TariffOption`, reffering the `DictTariff` is saved.